# Add items to the sap.m.list using declarative support

Tags: sapui5

I want to add items to the List using declaritive support.
For example:

this is my code. I want to put the list element where the mark saysing:

```
            // I want to insert elements here......
```

Thanks

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>
 <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
        type='text/javascript'
        src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.10/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-modules='sap.ui.core.DeclarativeSupport'
>
</script>


             <div data-sap-ui-type='sap.m.ListBase' > 
                <div data-sap-ui-aggregation="content"> 
                // I want to insert elements here......
                 </div> 
             </div> 


     <div data-sap-ui-type='sap.ui.ux3.NavigationBar'>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem" data-key="item1"data-text="Item with some text 3"></div>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem" data-key="item1" data-text="Item with some text 3"></div>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem" data-key="item1" data-text="Item with some text 3"></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suppose there is no documentation regarding this issue available as the focus is clearly on XML views. Please provide an running example otherwise it is hard to answer.

Comment: Which items do you want to insert? The NavigationItems?

Comment: In this case yes. but let me describe the problem more clearly. I want to **know** how to insert elements inside a containing element (aggregation). Like in this case, I want to add NavigationItems to the NavigationBar. But I also don't know how to add StandardListItem into a List, or elements into combo-box. I am working with declarative support, and I don't really know how to find examples on how to do that (how to do aggregation to *some* UI controls in declarative support...).

Comment: this page  https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f136c76f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm seems to answer

Comment: Thanks I saw it, but it doesn't help me to know how to do aggregation on each SAPUI5 declarative support tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples for declaritive support (HTML tags omited).

The first shows the NavigationBar you want:

```
    <head>
        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            type="text/javascript"
            src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-modules="sap.ui.core.DeclarativeSupport">
        </script>
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
                var navbar = sap.ui.core.DeclarativeSupport.compile(document.getElementById("navbar"));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
    </body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.ux3.NavigationBar">
            <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem" data-key="item1"data-text="Item with some text 3"></div>
            <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem" data-key="item1" data-text="Item with some text 3"></div>
            <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem" data-key="item1" data-text="Item with some text 3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The second one uses a List with a StandardListItem and model binding:

```
    <head>
        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            type="text/javascript"
            src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-modules="sap.ui.core.DeclarativeSupport">
        </script>
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
                var list = sap.ui.core.DeclarativeSupport.compile(document.getElementById("list"));
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                    "items" : [
                        { "name" : "Test" },
                        { "name" : "Declaritive Support"}]
                }), "data");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
    </body>
    <div id="list">
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.List" data-items="{data>/items}">
            <div data-sap-ui-aggregation="items">
                <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.StandardListItem" data-title="{data>name}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

More details can be found [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f130196f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html). Please note that you can't use ListBase as it is just a base implementation of list style controls, e.g. List or Table. It would be also possible to skip the div defining the aggregation as UI5 has a concept of default aggregation, which is items in this case. This can be seen in the first example as well.